# Cypress: get error message from DOM on test failure

Tags: cypress

In cypress, how can I extract some information from DOM (like error code) on test-failure ?
Is it even possible?

Following code wont work

```
Cypress.on('fail', (e, runnable) => {
     cy.contains(/[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}/).invoke('text').then((text) => {
       cy.PrintDebugInfo("Sentry-error: "+cy.wrap(text))
     });
})
```